# In how many different ways can 50 children be distributed in 5 identical classrooms

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, set-partition

This problem is solved using Stirling numbers of the second kind :

We can have empty classrooms

If no classroom is empty we get $S(50,5)$

If one classroom is empty we get $ {5}\choose{4 } $ $  S(50,4)$

If two classrooms are empty we get $ {5}\choose{3 } $ $  S(50,3)$

If three classrooms are empty we get $ {5}\choose{2 } $ $  S(50,2)$

If four classrooms a reempty we get $ {5}\choose{1 } $ $  S(50,1)$ which is 5

So the final is the sum of all 5 events? Am I right? Because the teacher didn't use the Binomial coefficient when calculating the partition and I think that is necessary.

Comment: What is $S(50,5)?$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: You should define that.  I don't think it is standard enough to go undefined.

Comment: Since class rooms are identical, the distribution needs to take care of how many empty classrooms are there. If four class rooms are empty, then there is only one way to put all the children in one class room.

Comment: @RossMillikan The question is about distributions, it mentions Stirling numbers in the text, and it's tagged `stirling-numbers`. For someone familiar with combinatorics, that's plenty to figure out what "S(50,5)" represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial coefficient isn't used because the classrooms are identical, thus having different classrooms be empty doesn't result in distributions that are considered different. Furthermore, if the classrooms were distinguishable, your binomials would not be correct. You are choosing $k$ classrooms to be empty, and there are $5$ classrooms, not $50$. So it should be $5\choose k$, not $50\choose k$.

Comment: Good point there! So the answer should be $ S(50,5) $ + $ S(50,4) $ + $ S(50,3) $ + $ S(50,2) $ + $ S(50,1) $ ?